# CryptoJs aes impacting cordova applications with Cordova-Plugin_camera

Tags: cordova, plugins, camera, aes, cryptojs

I have been struggling for figuring out the reason for failure of Cordova-plugin-camera for the last 45 days.

This really bugged me like hell and consumed more than required time for this.

I have nailed it now.

I was using cyrptojs aes to encrypt the device local stored user sensitive information.

It is being used inside winjs.xhr.

Not sure what is the reason but it is some how impacting the "state" of the application and any external operations such as "file" browsing/Camera click save and return to app is exiting the app.

Please reply if anybody has any information about this negative impact.

this cryptojs aes is from google.

CryptoJS v3.1.2
code.google.com/p/crypto-js
(c) 2009-2013 by Jeff Mott. All rights reserved.
code.google.com/p/crypto-js/wiki/License

anybody from google who may have done this utility, please reply.

Comment: I spent 600 hours on this. Please don't loose your work hours using this cryptojs from google that might be probably not suitable for cordova apps.

Comment: You can create a question and answer it yourself, but you would find out why it happened to do that. This site is not operated by Google, they won't answer. File a bug report at Cordova instead and see what they think about it.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, This is complex issue which can not be debugged as it is happening on devices and not in emulators. Second, to inform to those "if anybody from google...or cordova..and to microsoft folks those are supporting cordova platform..... then will be able to look into this.....third....this might be useful to other developers.....